# SSL: where is the certificate hosted? when does the verification occurs?

Tags: ssl, https, dns

I am quite confused here:

I use [DNSMadeeasy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/) to manage my DNS. I have two apps.

- One is Heroku hosted, and has https on https://example.com - Heroku has many great tutorials to setup the certificate, it hasn't been a problem.
- The other one is a wordpress, hosted in [1and1](https://www.1and1.com/) (though it shouldn't matter here), and is reachable at http://subdomain.example.com and we want it to be available at https://subdomain.example.com

1and1 does sell SSL certificate, but their automated setup works only when one uses their services for DNS also, as they say. Their support says it should be DNSMadeEasy which should be hosting our SSL certificate. I have the feeling it is not true, because for https://example.com, DNSMadeEasy was never involved.

Questions:

- When does certificate querying occurs? **Before**, **After**, or **in parallel of** DNS resolution?
- Who is hosting a certificate? **The DNS provider**? **The server** (accessible like a sitemap.xml at the root for instance)? **A third party**?
- To enlarge the case, in general if I have a personal server with a fix IP, how can I communicate through https with a valid certificate?
- In my case, how can I get my way out of it to make https://subdomain.example.com work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right for not believing the 1and1 suggestion.

To answer your questions:

- When does certificate querying occurs? Before, After, or in parallel 
  of DNS resolution?

A client resolves domain name to an IP address first. So DNS resolution happens first.

- Who is hosting a certificate?

The server (in simplistic terms) hosts the certificate.

When a client wants to connect to your site (via HTTPS) it will first establish a secure connection with that IP address on port 443 (this is why usually (without SNI) you can only have one SSL certificate per IP address). As part of this process (which is called handshake) a client can also specify a server name (so-called server name extension) - this is a domain name of your site. This is useful if you have an SSL certificate that is valid for multiple domains.

A good/detailed explanation how it works can be found here
http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html

- if I have a personal server with a fix IP, how can I communicate
  through https with a valid certificate?

Your server will need to be able to respond on port 443 and have/host an SSL certificate for a domain that resolves to that IP address.

- In my case, how can I get my way out of it to make
  https://subdomain.example.com work?

You need to purchase a certificate for subdomain.example.com and install it on the wordpress server. 
Usually in hosted solution like yours you have 2 options:

1. Buy the SSL certificate via the provider (1and1 in your case) - a simpler option, they will configure everything for you.
2. Buy the SSL certificate yourself. Here you will most likely need to login to your 1and1/Wordpress management interface and generate a CSR (essentially a certificate request). Then you purchase the SSL certificate using this CSR and then you can install it via the same management interface.
   The process will look similar to this:
   http://wpengine.com/support/add-ssl-site/